# FragmentTransaction.remove has no effect

Tags: android, fragment, overlap

My requirement is quite simple: I have a button that should replace a FragmentA by FragmentB.

This sounds easy and nearly work, the big problem is that the old fragment is not removed and the new placed on the front of the old one and they are "living" together in my layout.

[image]

**The Code:**

```
FragmentManager fragMgr = a.getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment currentFragment = (Fragment) fragMgr.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentitself);

if(currentFragment!=null){

     FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
     fragTrans.remove(currentFragment);

     FragmentB newFragment = new FragmentB();
     fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, newFragment);
     // I have also tried with R.id.fragmentitself
     fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
     fragTrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
     fragTrans.commit();
}
```

**The Layout:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentitself"
        android:name="com.WazaBe.MyApp.FragmentA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Solution**

First, you have to remove your fragment from XML and just keep empty container there:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer" />
```

Then you need to add your `com.WazaBe.MyApp.FragmentA` fragment from code, i.e. in `onCreate()` of your parent Activity.

**Explanation**

It is because your transactions manipulate content of `ViewGroup` such as said `FrameLayouts`. The catch is, that you can only manipulate elements you added from code as whatever is inflated from XML layout is considered "read-only". So when you put your Fragment directly into your XML layout, then it becomes **permanent** part of the view hierarchy and because it is permanent and the whole hierarchy is "read-only" it cannot be removed from code.

Once you get your layout fixed and Fragment extracted, the `remove()` call is no longer needed - it will suffice to just do `replace()`.

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski I have a ListView within FrameLayout. How will I add ListView from onCreate method? I am unable t do that. Plz help...

Comment: Not sure what you ask really, but we talk fragments here and ListView is not a fragment. You may want to post separate question if you need any help with your code.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to place a Fragment in a View Container(Such as a Framelayout),you must make sure that your container is empty(only this you can put a fragment into it).you cannot replace a fragment writed in XML file,you should add A into the container by JAVA code ,and when you don't neet id ,you can replace it by B;

at first ,your container is empyt:

```
<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="2" 
android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">
</FrameLayout>
```

OK,you put FragmentA into it:

```
 FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
 fragTrans.remove(currentFragment);
 FragmentA fragA= new FragmentA();
 fragTrans.add(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fragA).commit();
```

NOW,if you want to replace:

```
FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMgr.beginTransaction();
 FragmentB newFragment = new FragmentB();
 fragTrans.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, newFragment);
 // I have also tried with R.id.fragmentitself
 fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
 fragTrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
 fragTrans.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

if we use Fragment container on activity, it require select one default FragmentABC, the default FragmentABC view cannot removed even we use the ft.remove.

Use FrameLayout container instead of Fragment container if you want a empty view of fragment on activity startup.

Answer (score 0):

**Same Answer In Kotlin**

```
   private fun showDetailView(position: Int) {
            val fragTrans: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            val fragment: Fragment
            when (position) {
                0 -> fragment = FragmentA()
                1 -> fragment = FragmentB()
                else ->
                    fragment = FragmentC()
            }
            fragTrans.replace(
                    R.id.itemDetailContainer,
                    fragment).commit()
            fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
            fragTrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        }
    
    }
```